# academictwitteR get_user_timeline Error 400 API v2

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to get the full timeline of twitter user through the academictwitteR package and the twitter academic track API (v2). However, I get an error 400. Unfortunately, the explanation here https://developer.twitter.com/en/support/twitter-api/error-troubleshooting
says "The request was invalid or cannot be otherwise served. An accompanying error message will explain further. Requests without authentication or with invalid query parameters are considered invalid and will yield this response.", but the error code does not contain any explanation. I do not know what I am doing wrong. I tried other R packages as well, same error. I have access to all other functions of the API, but cannot adjust the timeline to download either more than 3200 tweets at a time (as my access should allow me to do). I want to full timeline of this user, not just the newest 3200 tweets.

The errorcode looks like that:

Error in make_query(url = endpoint_url, params = params, bearer_token = bearer_token,  :
something went wrong. Status code: 400

This is my request (I tried using the user ID, it does not change anything).

```
tmlne <- get_user_timeline("25390350",
                  start_tweets = "2009-03-19T00.00.00Z", 
                  end_tweets = "2021-11-27T00.00.00Z",
                  bearer_token = get_bearer(),
                  data_path = "twitter/data/timelines/",
                  n = 100000, 
                  bind_tweets = F,
                  file = "tmlnw")
```

I tried revoking and renewing the bearer token, I tested the token by downloading all tweets from a user (which is not what I am after, but just to see if my access works), that works, but the timelines do not. I can get 3200 with the get_timelines_v2 function of the TwitterV2 package, but I cannot circumvent the 3200 tweets limit and I do not know how to change the request to get older tweets than the most recent 3200, and I cannot get the academictwitteR package to use the timeline function (here I know how to make multiple requests).

What would help me is either an information regarding the Error 400 or how to adjust the get_timelines_v2 function to include older tweets.

Comment: There is a hard limit of 3200 Tweets on the timelines retrieval in both v1.1 and v2, even if you have Academic access. What you can do instead is to use the full archive search to find all of the Tweets posted by that user (which can go back further than the timeline limit)

Comment: Ah, dang. Thats what I feared. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the full archive search? You can use the query `from:username` to get all the Tweets posted by the user. What are you missing between that and the timeline endpoint?

Comment: That was what I was wondering too, why would there be two functions for the same result? What I found is that the format it comes out with is different, there are lists packed into the dataframe and the user names for responses are just displayed as IDs. It really comes down to convenience in the end if i understand the output correctly. It just requires a lot more detangling of the dataframe.